# UIPickerView toolbar buttons not working

Tags: ios7, uipickerview

I'm trying to add a toolbar to a `UIPicker`.
I've seen that the right way to go is this way:

```
UIToolbar* toolbarWeight= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(gotoNextField:)];
[toolbarWeight setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:barButtonNext1] animated:YES]; 

weightPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
[weightPickerView addSubview:toolbarWeight];
```

While:

```
-(IBAction)gotoNextField:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Works");
}
```

The picker works just fine but the button doesn't work. 
After doing some research, I've tried this approach:
(I suspected that the problem was related to the UIBarButtonItem action)

```
UIButton* myBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
myBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,24);
[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoNextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myBtn setTitle:@"Next!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonNext1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myBtn];
[toolbarWeight setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:barButtonNext1] animated:YES];
```

Doesn't work either. The button appears but doesn't get selected/respond to touchUpInside.

Comment: By 'doesn't work', do you mean that your button appears on screen, but nothing happens when you tap on it?

Comment: Exactly. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adding a toolbar to the pickerView, the toolbar is added behind the picker preventing the buttons from responding to touch events.

Encapsulating both the picker and the toolbar in a view, and making it an inputView (to make both the picker and the toolbar popup together) provides the desired solution.

```
weightPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216)];
weightPickerView.tag = 13;
UIView* genericWeightView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 219, 320, 266)];
[genericWeightView addSubview:toolbarWeight];
[genericWeightView  addSubview:weightPickerView];
```

and then:

```
[weight_txtField setInputView:genericWeightView];
```

Answer (score 14):

Here an example for adding a UIPickerView including a Toolbar - **works with iOS 7**

Make sure to implement the interfaces UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate and also implement the @selector methods

```
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
[pickerView setDataSource: self];
[pickerView setDelegate: self];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(itemWasSelected:)];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logoutData)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *clearButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(clearData)];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, clearButton, flexible, doneButton, nil]];

pickerParentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 260)];
[pickerParentView addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerParentView addSubview:toolBar];
[self.view addSubview:pickerParentView];
```